# android Drag and Drop don't Functionality to Move Objects on Finger Touch in Android(Especially zoom in, zoom out don't function)

Tags: android, touch, zooming, move, drag

this my xml :

```js
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            style="@style/custom_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="12"
         >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/ec_rltabselected"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <AbsoluteLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/border_rounding" >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivCardView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llBottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:weightSum="0" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_up"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

And my class :

```js
public class clothe_codi extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    ArrayList<String> arr_id_list;

    Clothe_DBHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    List<clothe_codi_mini_item> codi;
    RecyclerView recyclerView_mini_codi;

    //경계선

    private Button m_btnSelectImage, m_btnSDeleteImage, m_btnZoom;
    private Context m_context;
    private LinearLayout m_llTopLayout;
    private ImageView m_ivImage, m_ivtmpImage;
    private Display m_screen;
    private int m_DisplayWidth, m_ImageCount, m_viewsAddedHeightEmotions = 0,
            m_height, m_absHeight = 0, m_AddedViewsHeightText = 0,
            m_deleteEditHeightwidth;
    private Dialog m_dialog;
    private View.OnTouchListener m_touchImagListener, m_strecthArrowListener;
    private AbsoluteLayout m_absolutelayout, m_absTextlayout, m_absZoomlayout;
    private int m_widthDelete = 0, m_totalTextViewCount = 0;
    private float m_oldDist = 1f, m_scale, m_oldX = 0, m_oldY = 0, m_dX, m_dY,
            m_posX, m_posY, m_prevX = 0, m_prevY = 0, m_newX, m_newY;
    ViewTreeObserver m_vtoTree;
    private AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams m_layoutparams, m_layoutparamsDelete,
            m_layoutParamsEdit;
    private ArrayList<ViewsVo> m_arrSignObjects;
    private Bitmap m_bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.clothe_codi);

        //id데리고 오기
        arr_id_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        //db만들기
        helper = new Clothe_DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ref_back);
        //toolbar상단에 글씨설정
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("코디하기");

        recyclerView_mini_codi=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_up);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager_up=new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView_mini_codi.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView_mini_codi.setLayoutManager(layoutManager_up);
        codi=new ArrayList<>();
        //listview에 뿌려주기 위하여
        ClotheSelect();
        recyclerView_mini_codi.setAdapter(new clothe_codi_mini_item_RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),codi,R.layout.activity_main));
        recyclerView_mini_codi.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener(this, recyclerView_mini_codi,
                new RecyclerViewOnItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                        final Integer selectedPos = position;
                        String popo = arr_id_list.get(selectedPos);

                        Cursor search;
                        search = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clothe_list where _id = '" + popo + "';", null);
                        while (search.moveToNext()){

                            byte[] byteimage = search.getBlob(3);
                            Bitmap bitmapimage = DbBitmapUtility.getBitmap(byteimage);

                            getImageLayout(bitmapimage);

                        }
                        search.close();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View v, int position) {


                    }
                }
        ));



        //I made Drag and Drop to Move Objects on Finger Touch in Android
        m_context = clothe_codi.this;
        m_ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCardView);
        m_absolutelayout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
        m_llTopLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llBottomLayout);
        m_arrSignObjects = new ArrayList<ViewsVo>();
        // Set the layout parameters to the Absolute layout for adding images.
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl_pr = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        rl_pr.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.llBottomLayout);
        rl_pr.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.layout_title);
        m_absolutelayout.setLayoutParams(rl_pr);
        m_screen = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        m_DisplayWidth = m_screen.getWidth();
        m_AddedViewsHeightText = m_llTopLayout.getHeight();
        // Get the absoulte layout height according to the device screen density
        // to set the layout.
        m_vtoTree = m_absolutelayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        m_vtoTree.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                m_absHeight = m_absolutelayout.getHeight();
                m_absolutelayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
        m_dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Dialog);
        m_dialog.setCancelable(true);


    }

    public void ClotheSelect() {

        Cursor search;
        search = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clothe_list", null);
        while (search.moveToNext()){
            String up_down = search.getString(1);
            String clothename = search.getString(2);
            byte[] byteimage = search.getBlob(3);
            Bitmap bitmapimage = DbBitmapUtility.getBitmap(byteimage);

            codi.add(new clothe_codi_mini_item(up_down, clothename, bitmapimage));

            //id를 저장
            arr_id_list.add(search.getString(0));

        }
        search.close();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this) 를 사용할 경우 모든 Activity를 Destroy 시키고 부모 Activity로 돌아간다.
                // NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                // finish() 를 사용할 경우 현재 Activity를 Destroy하고 부모 Activity로 돌아간다.
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.setting:

                Intent timesetting = new Intent(clothe_codi.this, ref_time_setting.class);
                startActivity(timesetting);

                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    m_bitmap = null;
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    m_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                    getImageLayout(m_bitmap);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to set the view's height dynamically according to screen size.
     */
    private void setViewsHeightDynamically() {
        if (m_absHeight <= 500) {
            m_layoutparamsDelete = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20, 110,0);
            m_layoutParamsEdit = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(20, 20, 110,110);
            m_deleteEditHeightwidth = 20;
        } else if (m_absHeight >= 900) {
            m_layoutparamsDelete = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40, 130,0);
            m_layoutParamsEdit = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40, 130,130);
            m_deleteEditHeightwidth = 40;
        } else {
            m_layoutparamsDelete = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(35, 35, 140,0);
            m_layoutParamsEdit = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(35, 35, 120,120);
            m_deleteEditHeightwidth = 35;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method to add the image by setting and creating the views dynamically
     * with delete and zoom option.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void getImageLayout(Bitmap p_bitmap) {
        ViewsVo m_signVo;
        //Check for images count .Set the count for limiting the number of images to add on screen.
        if (m_ImageCount < 1) {
            m_viewsAddedHeightEmotions = m_viewsAddedHeightEmotions + 90;
            m_ImageCount++;
        }
        m_btnSDeleteImage = new Button(m_context);
        m_btnZoom = new Button(m_context);
        m_ivtmpImage = new ImageView(m_context);
        setViewsHeightDynamically();
        m_btnSDeleteImage.setLayoutParams(m_layoutparamsDelete);
        m_btnSDeleteImage.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.ic_deletered));
        m_btnSDeleteImage.setId(0);
        m_btnSDeleteImage.setOnClickListener(new ImageDeleteListener());
        m_btnZoom.setLayoutParams(m_layoutParamsEdit);
        m_btnZoom.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.right_arrow));
        m_btnZoom.setId(0);
        m_absTextlayout = new AbsoluteLayout(m_context);
        m_absZoomlayout = new AbsoluteLayout(m_context);
        //500여기 숫자를 늘리면 이미지 자체 화질이 좋아진다.
        m_ivtmpImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(p_bitmap, 500, 500, true));
        m_absTextlayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0));
        m_absZoomlayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0));
        if (m_absHeight >= 900)
            //setLayoutParams를 이용하여 위의 이미지 크기를 지정한다.
            m_ivtmpImage.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        else
            m_ivtmpImage.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80));
        m_ivtmpImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        m_absTextlayout.addView(m_btnSDeleteImage);
        if (m_absHeight >= 900)
            m_absZoomlayout.setPadding(20, 20, 15, 15);
        else
            m_absZoomlayout.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        /*m_absZoomlayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dashedbordersmall);*/
        m_absZoomlayout.addView(m_ivtmpImage);
        m_absTextlayout.addView(m_absZoomlayout);
        m_absTextlayout.addView(m_btnZoom);
        m_absTextlayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        m_absTextlayout.setClickable(true);
        m_absTextlayout.setId(0);
        m_ivtmpImage.setId(0);
        m_vtoTree =m_absTextlayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        m_vtoTree.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                m_absTextlayout.getViewTreeObserver()
                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
        /**
         * Add all the views into arraylist which are added into the screen for
         * further to perform deletion of each views.
         */
        m_signVo = new ViewsVo();
        m_arrSignObjects.add(0, m_signVo);
        m_absolutelayout.addView(m_absTextlayout);
        // Image touch listener to move image onTouch event on screen.
        m_touchImagListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        m_oldX = event.getX();
                        m_oldY = event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        m_dX = event.getX() - m_oldX;
                        m_dY = event.getY() - m_oldY;
                        m_posX = m_prevX + m_dX;
                        m_posY = m_prevY + m_dY;
                        if (m_posX > 0 && m_posY > 0&& (m_posX + v.getWidth()) < m_absolutelayout.getWidth()&& (m_posY + v.getHeight()) < m_absolutelayout.getHeight())
                        {
                            v.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(),(int) m_posX, (int) m_posY));
                            m_prevX = m_posX;
                            m_prevY = m_posY;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        // Listener for the arrow ontouch of arrow ZoomIn and ZoomOut the image.
        m_strecthArrowListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                View view;
                view = v;
                v.setClickable(true);
                v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                AbsoluteLayout m_absLayout = null;
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        m_oldX = event.getX();
                        m_oldY = event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        m_newX = event.getX();
                        m_newY = event.getY();
                        float newDist = m_newX - m_oldX;
                        if (m_newX > m_oldX && m_newY > m_oldY) {
                            if (newDist > 0.0f) {
                                m_scale = 1;
                                m_absLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) v.getParent();
                                int m_hightOfImage = (int) (m_scale + (((ImageView) ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getHeight()));
                                int m_widthOfImage = (int) (m_scale + (((ImageView) ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getWidth()));
                                m_widthDelete = (int) (m_scale + ((((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1))).getWidth()));
                                if (m_absLayout.getBottom() <= (m_ivImage.getBottom())
                                        && m_absLayout.getRight() <= (m_DisplayWidth)) {
                                    m_layoutparams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams( m_widthOfImage, m_hightOfImage, 0, 0);
                                    ((ImageView) ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).setLayoutParams(m_layoutparams);
                                    m_layoutparams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams( AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,m_absLayout.getLeft(), m_absLayout.getTop());
                                    m_absLayout.setLayoutParams(m_layoutparams);
                                    ((Button) m_absLayout.getChildAt(0)).setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(m_deleteEditHeightwidth,m_deleteEditHeightwidth,m_widthDelete, 0));
                                    ((Button) m_absLayout.getChildAt(2)).setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(m_deleteEditHeightwidth,m_deleteEditHeightwidth,m_widthDelete, m_widthDelete));
                                    m_hightOfImage = (int) (m_scale + (((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getHeight()));
                                    m_widthOfImage = (int) (m_scale + (((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getWidth()));
                                    m_layoutparams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams( m_widthOfImage, m_hightOfImage,((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout .getChildAt(1)).getLeft(),((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout .getChildAt(1)).getTop());
                                    ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).setLayoutParams(m_layoutparams);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (m_newX < m_oldX && m_newY < m_oldY) {
                            m_absLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) view.getParent();
                            int m_hightOfImage = (int) (((ImageView) ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getHeight() - m_scale);
                            int m_widthOfImage = (int) (((ImageView) ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).getWidth() - m_scale);
                            m_widthDelete = (int) (((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getWidth() - m_scale);
                            m_layoutparams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams( m_widthOfImage, m_hightOfImage, 0, 0);
                            ((ImageView) ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(0)).setLayoutParams(m_layoutparams);
                            m_layoutparams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    m_absLayout.getLeft(), m_absLayout.getTop());
                            m_absLayout.setLayoutParams(m_layoutparams);
                            ((Button) m_absLayout.getChildAt(0)).setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(m_deleteEditHeightwidth,
                                    m_deleteEditHeightwidth, m_widthDelete,0));
                            ((Button) m_absLayout.getChildAt(2)).setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(m_deleteEditHeightwidth,
                                    m_deleteEditHeightwidth, m_widthDelete,m_widthDelete));
                            m_hightOfImage = (int) ((((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout
                                    .getChildAt(1)).getHeight()) - m_scale);
                            m_widthOfImage = (int) ((((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout
                                    .getChildAt(1)).getWidth()) - m_scale);
                            m_layoutparams = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    m_widthOfImage, m_hightOfImage, ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getLeft(),((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1)).getTop());
                            ((AbsoluteLayout) m_absLayout.getChildAt(1))
                                    .setLayoutParams(m_layoutparams);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        m_absTextlayout.setOnTouchListener(m_touchImagListener);
        m_btnZoom.setOnTouchListener(m_strecthArrowListener);
    }
    // Delete button listener to show the alert and confirmation for deleting
    // the items.
    private class ImageDeleteListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    m_context);
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Drag & Drop");
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete ?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int id) {
                                    m_ImageCount--;
                                    for (int counter = 0; counter < m_arrSignObjects
                                            .size(); counter++) {
                                        if (v.getId() == m_arrSignObjects.get(counter).getViewId()) {
                                            if (m_totalTextViewCount <= 0) {
                                                m_AddedViewsHeightText = m_AddedViewsHeightText
                                                        - m_arrSignObjects.get(counter).getViewHeight();
                                            } else {
                                                m_totalTextViewCount--;
                                            }
                                            m_absolutelayout.removeView((View) v
                                                    .getParent());
                                            m_arrSignObjects.remove(counter);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

I made Drag and Drop to Move Objects on Finger Touch in Android

Reference site this : http://grishma102.blogspot.kr/2013/10/drag-and-drop-functionality-to-move.html

But, my activity's zoom in, zoom out don't function
When I move objects on Finger Touch, the objects just zoom out and screen out.

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding OnDrag() listener instead of onTouch()

```
view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    return true;
}
});
```